Is it safe to proced with upgrade of Ubuntu dual booted with Windows 11
I am updating Ubuntu and am getting a configuring secure boot message.  The system is a Intel NUC and is dual booted with Windows 11 and Ubuntu.  I think when installing Win 11 I had to disable secure boot and am just asking if I can proceed past this configuring secure boot screen or if I will not be able to boot into to Windows 11 after.
Thanks


"I think when installing Win 11 I had to disable secure boot" Apparently not, as Secure Boot looks quite enabled in your screenshot.

Yeah, I guess so but will it affect dual booting I think it was bitlocker I disabled now that I am looking at this.  Just wanted to be sure.

If you have bitlocker enabled, you will need to apply the recovery password every time linux updates grub, assuming you use the grub menu to boot windows.  This has nothing to do with secure boot.  Secure boot is safe for both linux and windows, but your linux drivers wont load correctly if you don't follow the directions in your screen shot.  If you fail to follow them, there are ways to retrigger the MOK enrollment.

@user10489 the last two sentences look like a very good answer.

Thanks I went ahead with the update
